# Routing traffic back and forth through a Mac mini server with 2 network interfaces

Tags: network, mac-mini, internet, internet-sharing, router

I have my office network that looks like this:

[image: networking scheme]

My office network looks like this:

- the office network (wifi and wired) has the subnetwork `192.168.88.0`.
- I have some server machines on the subnetwork `192.168.2.0` (NODE_1,.... NODE_10).
- I have a machine (it is a Mac mini) with 2 subnetwork interfaces that acts as:

  - the gateway for all machines in subnetwork  `192.168.2.0`.
  - exposes a VPN service (the Mac server app default one)
  - and provides extra services, such as a DNS)

The Mac mini configuration is my big problem. This is how it looks:

**Ethernet interface en0**

- address: `192.168.88.10`
- netmask: `255.255.255.0`
- gateway: `192.168.88.1`

**Ethernet interface en2**

- address: `192.168.2.1`
- netmask: `255.255.255.0`
- gateway: `192.168.88.10`

I need routing from machines in `192.168.88.0` to those in `192.168.2.0`.

To do so I have activated the ***"Internet sharing"*** feature of Mac OS: actually I do not know what happens under the hood, but the machines **NODE_1** ...**NODE_10** go to internet.

Then, when I'm connected to the office network, so that I get an IP such as: `192.168.88.33` I add a routing rule such as:

```
 sudo route -n add 192.168.2.0/24 -gateway 192.168.88.10
```

So far so good: everything works fine!!!!!

The big problem is when I connect through the VPN.

### VPN Connection

I connect successfully to the VPN exposed at: `192.168.88.10`, then I add the routing rule.

```
 sudo route -n add 192.168.2.0/24 -gateway 192.168.88.10
```

I'm not able to reach the machines in subnet `192.168.2.0`.

Sniffing the packets I see that the packets follow the hops:

1. -> 192.168.88.10
2. -> 192.168.2.1
3. -> 192.168.2.110
4. <- 192.168.2.1
5. <- 192.168.88.1

The packet goes to the gateway `192.168.88.1` instead of the `192.168.88.10`. Looking into the Mac mini routing tables I see:

```
192.168.88.202     192.168.88.10      UH              2       93    ppp1
192.168.88.202     40:6c:8f:3:d5:e7   UHLS2           0        0     en0
```

`40:6c:8f:3:d5:e7` is the mac address of `192.168.88.1`.

I would like to change the routing without using the **internet sharing** in order to allow internet access for `192.168.2.0`, and cover both the VPN and local scenario, but I don't know the steps I need to do, and how to hand write the rules.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: 1. You have two default gateways: the one set for en2 is wrong - it should be nada/nothing. 2. You have a double-NAT: 1st is your ADSL router 2nd is your Mac mini en1>en2 (internet Sharing!) 3. Is it possible to setup a static route on your ADSL router? 4. Please add your system/macOS server version. 5. How did you set up forwarding on your ADSL router (to get VPN working)?

Comment: 3. unfortunately no
4. El Capitan
5. I opened the ports for the L2TP protocol and forwarded to the 192.168.88.10 machine.

Comment: the router is the default vodafone one, the "vodafone station revolution". It should be the Huawei hhg2500.

Comment: where do MacOs store the network ip tables, and configuration files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be possible to create a bridge with en0 and en2 and enable net.inet.ip.forwarding to get rid of all routing problems. The bridge acts more or less as another switch between en0 and en2.

---

- Disable Internet Sharing
- remove the gateway in the en2 settings of the Mac mini and change the IP-address to an available one in 192.168.88.0/24 (e.g. 192.168.88.11)
- remove all additional static routes
- Check for bridge interfaces with `ifconfig`
- On the server create a file *bridge*:

  ```
  sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin/ #only if the folder is missing
  sudo nano /usr/local/bin/bridge
  ```

  with the content

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
  ifconfig bridge create
  ifconfig bridge0 addm en0 addm en2 up #use the first available bridge number here and the proper interface device names
  ```
- enter `sudo chmod +x nano /usr/local/bin/bridge`
- Create a launch daemon *usr.bridge.plist*:

  ```
  sudo nano /Library/LaunchDaemons/usr.bridge.plist
  ```

  with the content

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
  <plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
      <key>Label</key>
      <string>usr.bridge</string>
      <key>ProgramArguments</key>
      <array>
          <string>/bin/sh</string>
          <string>-c</string>
          <string>/usr/local/bin/bridge</string>
      </array>
      <key>RunAtLoad</key>
      <true/>
      <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
      <string>/tmp/usr.bridge.err</string>
      <key>StandardOutPath</key>
      <string>/tmp/usr.bridge.out</string>
  </dict>
  </plist>
  ```
- Load the plist

  ```
  sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/usr.bridge.plist
  ```
- Change the IP-addresses of node_1 and node_10 to available ones in 192.168.88.0/24 (e.g. 192.168.88.101 and 192.168.88.110). Change their default gateways to 192.168.88.1 and the DNS server to 192.168.88.10.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the long answer! actually I would prefer to keep the 192.168.2.0 separate from the 192.168.88.0. Would it be possible with a bridge?

Comment: @JayZee This doesn't make much sense: you want to access everything from all devices but without Internet Sharing/NAT. Then you either have to create a lot of additional static routes (one route will fail because you apparently can't add static routes on your router) or you create such a bridge.